# How can I get Adobe Flash Player instlled?

Tags: windows-10, flash, adobe-flash

Whenever I try to install Adobe Flash Player, nothing happens.
How can I make Adobe Flash Player Active?
I have tried to get it installed through multiple browsers, (Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge and Firefox. I use and Asus All-in-one computer. I've never caused any damage to it, I just got it last year. I have a anti-virus on it, Ive never seen any viruses on it.
I am pretty new to windows 10, so maybe I just haven't found it yet?
So I am very confused. please help.

Comment: Can you provide something more descriptive other than "nothing happens"?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to install crapware like flash? Let it die already.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flash player is already included with most modern browsers, FireFox, Edge, Chrome, etc all have flash pre-installed/installation requirement.

A nice website that I found should be able to check which version of Adobe Flashplayer you have installed: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-flash-installed
It does require JavaScript though so while this is not uncommon you may need to install/given permission to run if you are having trouble with Adobe Flashplayer.

When downloading Adobe Flashplayer you have to be very careful as to its source, as I have found quite a few websites offering concerning links to malware filled installers, I suggest using the official site to download Adobe found here: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Answer (score 0):

The following instructions are how you enable Adobe Flash Player on the three browsers you asked about.

### [Enable Flash on Microsoft Edge](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-issues-windows-10-edge.html):

> 1. Click the "..." button to access the Edge menu.
> 2. Select the Settings menu item.
> 3. Scroll down to the Advanced Settings section and click the View advanced settings button.
> 4. Locate the Use Adobe Flash Player section and toggle the switch on to enable Adobe Flash Player.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. Refresh your web page or open a new browser tab.

### [Enable Flash on Firefox](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-firefox.html):

> 1. Choose Firefox > Tools > Add-ons.
> 2. Select Plugins.
> 3. In the list of Add-ons, look for Shockwave Flash (another name for Flash Player) and check the status that appears to the right of the
>      plug-in name.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. Select Always Activate.
> 6. Close the dialog box.

### [Enable for Internet Explorer](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/install-flash-player-windows.html):

> 1. Click the Tools icon in the upper-right corner of Internet Explorer. (The icon looks like a gear.)
> 2. In the pop-up menu that appears, click Manage Add-ons.
> 3. In the dialog box that appears, select Toolbars and Extensions.
> 4. In the list of Add-ons, look for “Shockwave Flash Object” (another name for Flash Player).  In the Status column, check to see whether
>      Shockwave Flash Object is Disabled. If it is disabled, click the row
>      for Shockwave Flash Object to highlight it.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. In the lower-right corner of the Manage Add-ons dialog box, click Enable.
> 6. Close the Manage Add-ons dialog box.

Source: [Install Flash Player in five easy steps](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html)